# LDAP different passwords for different applications

Tags: passwords, ldap

So as far as I found out it is possible to assign multiple passwords to a LDAP-user. However what I'm trying to figure out is if one could limit one password to a specific application.

As far as I'm concerned this looks like the opposite of what one would like to achieve with using LDAP, however this is my task and I'm trying to go with it.

I explicitly do no want to create seperate users but just two passwords where one logs me into let's say my homepage backend and the other into my email but not the other way around!

Is this doable? I did not find any solutions so far.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Once you're bound as a user, via any of that user's passwords, you *are* that user, with all the groups and roles that that user is a member of.

Comment: Okay, just as I expected. Thanks for your answer.